# Remove indentation

Tags: code-golf, string, whitespace

Write a program which removes any common leading spaces from the input string. For example, if the *least* indented line started with 3 spaces, and every other line has `>=` 3 leading spaces, then remove 3 spaces from the beginning of each line.

The indentation consists solely of spaces, and the string will not contain any tabulation. This is the same as the `textwrap.dedent` function in python.

Example (input, output):

#### Input

```
       7aeiou
   3b
     555
```

#### Output

```
    7aeiou
3b
  555
```

#### Input

```
this
 is
  a
   test
```

#### Output

```
this
 is
  a
   test
```

#### Input

```
    Hello 
 world
```

#### Output

```
   Hello 
world
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not familiar with Python. Can you explain what the `dedent` function does, so we can replicate it without needing to know Python? Thanks!

Comment: please don't override PPCG's default submission guidelines. It's usually perfectly fine to submit functions without calling them, and allowing input as a predefined variable just turns submissions into snippets

Comment: Additionally, this looks very close to being a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53219/42963

Comment: It seems that example text looses 3 leading spaces on each line? Is this what the task is? May we assume that input always has at least 3 spaces on each line? May we assume a variable to hold a list of strings if this is more natural to our language?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, thanks, I didn't know what the minimum proper question could be.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 11 bytes

```perl6
*.indent(*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfSy8zLyU1r0RDS/O/NVdxYqVCmoaSAgSYJ6Zm5pdyAVnGSVxgEVNTUyXN/wA)